# Atributo Case Sensitive

Tags: angular, ionic, atributos

Boa tarde pessoal!

Tenho uma classe chamada Inventory que tem os seguintes atributos:

```
import InventoryItem from "./InventoryItem";
import InventoryConfiguration from "./InventoryConfiguration";

export default class Inventory {
  id: string;

  inventoryStatus: InventoryStatus;

  inventoryConfiguration: InventoryConfiguration;

  creationDate: Date;

  inventoryItems: InventoryItem[];

  inventoryReadedItems: InventoryItem[];
}
```

E no meu serviço de API, faço um get da seguinte forma:

```
  async getInventory(id: string): Promise<Inventory> {
    this.store.select(a => a.user.token).subscribe(a => (this.userToken = a));

    return this.http
      .get<Inventory>(this.baseUrl + `/Inventories/${id}`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${this.userToken.access_token}`
        }
      })
      .toPromise();
  }
```

Porém, na hora de utilizar o serviço para verificar se retornou um valor no Id, o meu método `getInventory` que deveria retornar exatamente igual o da classe, pois eu tipei.

Mas, está voltando o campo `id` como `Id` (I maiúsculo).. Assim, quando vou fazer o if abaixo, ele cai no else por causa disso, podem me ajudar a como resolver este problema?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 0):

Olá, apesar do Typescript tipar seus dados ele vai vir exatamente como vem do backend. Tem uma diferença entre tipar e fazer um casting. Se você falar pro typescript que seu back vai te mandar bananas e na prática te mandar maçãs ele não vai saber converter de um pro outro e vai te mandar maçãs.

Nesse caso ou vc faz a interface exatamente como vem do back ou faz um map do estado da api pro estado da aplicação.